# Expo Publish Equivalent for EAS Expo Application Service

Tags: react-native, expo

I have just migrated my project from expo classic to eas via documentation provided by expo.

Now, I need to update the App over the air which was previously possible with "expo publish" command.

This is the error message I get when I use "expo publish" after migration -

```
> expo publish
It seems like your project is configured for EAS Update. Please use 'eas branch:publish' instead.
```

Further on running "eas branch:publish" it return another error message -

```
> eas branch:publish
Error: deprecated, use "eas update"
```

Finally, after executing "eas update" it gave another error -

```
✔ Please enter an update message. … minor ui fixes
✔ Built bundle!
✔ Uploaded assets!
✖ Failed to published updates
CombinedError: [GraphQL] EAS Update is not yet publicly available.
```

Is there any way to publish updates over the air with eas just like "expo publish" ?

Comment: Any Updates on this?  From the docs it seems like we should be able to still use expo publish for the time being, but when I use expo publish nothing updates...

Comment: expo publish worked for me running sdk 44 on an eas build

Comment: @P-A so you were able to get you're published app to update via expo publish.  Workflow I publish an app out to google play or to ios app store.  I then make dev changes to the app and now I do expo publish... The app in the stores should update upon reopen.  This no longer seems to work.  The eas publish app doesn't seem to look for the update from the expo publish anymore like the classic build used to.

Comment: @BenWalton yes I got it working note though that I don't set any runtime-version and that I set a releaseChannel

Answer (score 10):

Got the same issue after some research, it seems we've both been locked behind a paywall.
According to this [update post](https://blog.expo.dev/eas-update-in-preview-d221b6f91f52) in December 2020.

> EAS Update preview is available to EAS Production plan subscribers (up
> to 100,000 updates/mo) and EAS Enterprise plan subscribers (up to
> 1,000,000 updates/mo). **In 2022, EAS Update will be publicly
> available with a free tier.**

A more [recent update](https://blog.expo.dev/eas-build-april-preview-update-ebd7dff9dd25) with new EAS features in April 2021 re-iterates

> As a reminder, previews of EAS Build and Submit are available to
> developers subscribed to the EAS Priority Plan, and they won’t be
> available on a free tier until they graduate from preview

https://expo.dev/pricing

[EAS plan pricing tiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBviW.png)

Free tier doesn't include Preview EAS Update.

Comment: So there is no way to do and Over the Air update once you start to use EAS build unless you pay to use eas update?  The documentation says you should still be able to use expo publish with eas build, but after attempting this it does not seem to work?

Comment: any idea about how to remove eas update ?
because i cant use expo publish now :((

Answer (score 2):

This is no more a concern.

If you check the billing page(https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/introduction/), you can see the section of `EAS Update`, this is the expo publish equivalent.

More info: https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

As of today, when I tried:

```
$ npx expo publish
```

I got this error:

> expo publish is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas update instead

What I've done is running

```
npm install -g eas-cli
```

Then:

```
eas login
```

And

```
eas build --platform android
```

See [the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/) for more details